# LTE applications

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponentiation

Let k be a positive integer. Find all positive integers n such that

$3^k | 2^n - 1$

I just started reading and learning about the Lifting the Exponents Lemma, and I want to try and use it in this problem.

So I know that if that said statement is true, then

$V_3(2^n - 1) > 0$

I guess you can express it as$V_3(2^n - 1^n)$, but in the lifting the exponent lemmas, I can't find one theorem that can solve the above expression, since 3 does not divide 2-1.

Comment: Right, but $3|2^2-1$.